# Macbook pro13 (2015) Battery dropping significantly during sleep

Tags: macbook-pro, battery, sleep-wake, console

I went through articles, but I'm requesting an answer for my instance. The relevant details are shown below,

```
Health Information:
Cycle Count:  336
Condition:    Normal
Health: 90%
```

According to the console, it seems like something is happening.[image]

[image]

The Mac, was put to sleep at 23:08, and according to the console it seems like it has been doing something.. so please give me expert advice, for that period about 8hours,  20% of the battery has drained :/
There are more stuff in the console, but I can post only 2 links here

Comment: [battery graph](http://imgur.com/a/9UEzf#963MRDw)

Answer (score 1):

Check with `pmset -g log` what is causing your Macbook to wake up.
Most likely it's due to network activity.

Install `PleaseSleep` from https://github.com/xinstein/PleaseSleep to workaround the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest going into Activity Monitor and see if there is any tasks using lots of CPU. I'd also recommend uninstalling/deleting any software that didn't come with the machine that you don't use or don't know how it because installed on your machine in the first place.

Also make sure you do all your app and system updates and restart your machine. If the issue persists I'd recommend taking it to an Apple Store or an authorised Apple Service centre and having a professional have a look